# Dependency is not present in the overall POM file

Tags: maven, maven-3

Apache Velocity needs commons-collections-3.2.1.

In my pom file I have added a velocity dependency. Everything works, but when I look in the overall pom file:

```
$ mvn help:effective-pom
```

I do not see an commons-collections entry.

I had expected it should be there. Or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, not if you don't specify it directly. `effective-pom` shows the pomfile factored in with the eventually inherited definitions from the parent pom (ie. dependencyManagement, pluginManagement, properties and so on) and the profile.

To see the full list of dependencies, including transitive dependencies, you need maven-dependency-plugin, and

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

The `effective-pom` does not show you all the transitive dependencies, only the POM as it will be, given whatever parents, profiles etc. you have.

You may want to try `mvn dependency:tree`, which will show you the projects' direct and transitive dependencies as a tree, and notice that commons-collections will be somewhere under Velocity.

Cheers,